# Equation of a curve

Tags: functions, curves

> **EDIT :** What is the equation for [**this function**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsyOB.jpg) ?

- Before editing **(no longer consider)**

  What is the function that goes through these points ?

  $f(0) = 2$

  $f(1) = 3$

  $f(2) = 0$

  $f(3) = 1$

  The curve looks like [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4RSe.jpg).

Comment: what properties should $F$ have? you can have it piecewise constant (and discontinuous) or piecewise linear (and not differentiable) or can try to fit a cubic polynomial -- what properties of $F$ are you looking for?

Comment: There are infinitely many functions passing thorough any given $4$ points.

Comment: This is quite similar to a constant sinusoidal function. - @gt6989b

Comment: What do you mean by a "constant sinusoidal function"?

Comment: I arranged to add an image of the curve to my question. - @RobertIsrael

Comment: Could you help here please ? Thank You. - @FranklinP.Dyer

Comment: Pouvez-vous m'aider ici s'il vous plaît ? Merci Beaucoup. - @Jennifer

Comment: I will appreciate your help here, thank you sir.- @JohnDoe

Comment: @EenAmok It seems like Robert Israel has the correct answer

Comment: Thanks for the interest. I updated the image in the question. Both curves do not seem to be the same. - @JohnDoe

Comment: I updated the question, is it clearer now ? - @Arnaldo

Comment: @EenAmok Most likely this question will now stay closed (statistically, questions re-open very rarely). Try to make the most out of the five  answers that are already given.

Comment: Alternatively, try to explain which answer is closest to what you want and explain exactly the ways in which it is not what you want. For example, it seems the function must stay in the range $[0,3].$ Is it also necessary for it to be differentiable everywhere? What are the restrictions on its slope (how "wiggly" can it be)? Or you might just want to look at cubic splines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a periodic solution defined for $x\in[-2.5,1.5]$ and looking much like the OP's sketch.

(For $x\notin[-2.5,1.5]$, continue periodically with period 4.)

$$\textstyle F(x)={3\over2}
-{52\over2205}(x+{1\over2})^7
+{2\over2205}(x+{1\over2})^5
+{1163\over8820}(x+{1\over2})^3
+{237\over245}(x+{1\over2}).
$$

Note that $F(x)\in[0,3]$ for all $x$; in particular,
$$\textstyle F(-2)=0, \ \ F(-1)=1, \ \ F(0)=2, \ \ F(1)=3, \ \ F({3\over2})={3\over2}, 
$$
$$
F'(-2)=0, \ \ F'(1)=0. \tag{$*$}
$$

Here is a WolframAlpha command to plot this solution.

```
plot 3/2-52/2205(x+.5)^7+2/2205(x+.5)^5+1163/8820(x+.5)^3+237/245(x+.5) from -2.5 to 1.5
```

**To continue with period 4:** in the function formula replace all occurrences of $(x+{1\over2})$ with $$(((x+2.5)\%4)-2)
$$
where $\%4$ denotes the operation of taking the remainder of division by $4$.
Below is a WolframAlpha command that plots the periodically continued function (Wolfram syntax for $\%4$ is `mod4`):

```
plot 3/2-52/2205(((x+2.5)mod4)-2)^7+2/2205(((x+2.5)mod4)-2)^5+1163/8820(((x+2.5)mod4)-2)^3+237/245(((x+2.5)mod4)-2) from -2.5 to 10
```

**This solution was obtained by:**

(1) noticing that if we place the origin of a new coordinate system at $(-{1\over2},{3\over2})$, then in the new coordinates the curve is an odd function;

(2) determining the unknown coefficients of a 7th-degree polynomial by solving a system of linear equations, to satisfy conditions equivalent to $(*)$;

(3) transforming the result back into the $(x,y)$ coordinates;

(4) periodic continuation.

Comment: Thanks for the interest. I updated the image in the question. I think it is clearer and it does not correspond to this polynomial.

Comment: Please look at the updated solution above. It looks almost exactly like your picture.

Comment: This is it ! But how do I perform "For $x∉[−2.5,1.5]$, continue periodically with period 4." ?

Comment: I updated the answer explaining how to continue with period 4.

Comment: It really looks like the function I'm looking for. It's really amazing, how did you do it ? - The function still seems to be discontinuous on WolframAlpha. Is this really the case or is it a display problem?

Comment: The function is in fact continuous. I also do see a small gap in Wolfram plot; it might be an algorithmic glitch in either computation or display on WolframAlpha.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. However the function of Robert Israel seems to me to be easier to handle. Is there not a way to adjust it so that it resembles [**this one**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsyOB.jpg) ? - @RobertIsrael

Comment: In many cases, unfortunately, the prettier the picture, the uglier formulas we have to use to make it. I am afraid this is the case here too; so Robert's formula will probably become less good-looking if we tweak it to make a nicer picture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58356/discussion-between-alex-and-een-amok).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a periodic function of period $4$, you might try something like
$$ f(x) = \frac{3}{2} + \cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) + \sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) - \frac{\cos (\pi x)}{2} $$

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the desired curve
is a polynomial.

Any 4 points like this
can be fitted to a cubic.
So a cubic is sufficient.

There is a maximum between 
0 and 2
and a minimum between
1 and 3.
Since there are 
at least two points
where
f'(x) = 0,
the curve is at least
a cubic.

Therefore
a cubic is the 
lowest degree polynomial
that works.

Now go and find it.

Comment: I added an image to show the only curve I'm talking about. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the interest. I updated the image in the question. I think it is clearer now. It is the one of which I want the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Such an equation is not uniquely determined, without some structural constraints.

However, if restricted to polynomials, there is a unique polynomial $p(x)$ with rational coefficients and degree at most $3$ such that
$$p(0)=2,\;\;p(1)=3,\;\;p(2)=0,\;\;p(3)=1$$
given by
$$p(x)={\small{\frac{4}{3}}}x^3-6x^2+{\small{\frac{17}{3}}}x+2$$
obtained via the Lagrange Interpolation formula:

$\qquad$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

The graph of $p$ does go through the required points, and its shape resembles the one you show in your posted image, but the relative extreme points of $p$ are not exactly the same as the ones in that image.

Also, your latest edit indicates that you want the function to be periodic function with period $4$, and everywhere nonnegative. Of course, a non-constant polynomial can't match those additional conditions. But I'll leave my answer in place, since it addresses the question as it was before the latest edit.

As to whether a polynomial exists which matches both the value conditions and the relative extrema conditions, I'm not sure, but I've posed that question (i.e,. $P$ restricted to polynomials, and matching values as well as relative extrema)

$\qquad$[Finding a polynomial with a given shape](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266293)

as a followup to your question

Comment: Thanks for the interest. I updated the image in the question. I think it is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The $\color{blue}{@marty cohen}$ solution:

**Problem specification**

We start with a sequence of $m=4$ measurements of the form $\left\{ x_{k}, y_{k}
\right\}_{k=1}^{m}$.

$$
 y(x) = a_{0} + a_{1} x + a_{2} x^{2} + a_{3} x^{4}
$$

**Linear system**
$$
%
\begin{align}
% 
 \mathbf{A} a &= y\\
% ATA
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & x_{1} & x^{2}_{1} & x^{3}_{1}\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 1 & x_{m} & x^{2}_{m} & x^{3}_{m}\\
\end{array}
\right]
% a
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{0} \\
 a_{1} \\
 a_{2} \\
 a_{3}
\end{array}
\right]
%
&=
% y
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 y_{1} \\
 \vdots \\
 y_{m}
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
%
$$

**Normal equations**
$$
%
\begin{align}
%
\mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} a &= \mathbf{A}^{*} y \\
% ATA
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 4 & 6 & 14 & 36 \\
 6 & 14 & 36 & 98 \\
 14 & 36 & 98 & 276 \\
 36 & 98 & 276 & 794 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% a
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{0} \\
 a_{1} \\
 a_{2} \\
 a_{3}
\end{array}
\right]
%
&=
% ATy
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 6 \\
 6 \\
 12 \\
 30
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
%
$$

**Least squares solution**
$$
%
\begin{align}
%
a &= \left( \mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{*} y \\
%
&=
\frac{1}{18}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 18 & -33 & 18 & -3 \\
 -33 & 265 & -225 & 47 \\
 18 & -225 & 207 & -45 \\
 -3 & 47 & -45 & 10 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% ATy
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 6 \\
 6 \\
 12 \\
 30
\end{array}
\right] \\
& =
% 
\frac{1}{3}
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 6 \\
 17 \\
-18 \\
 4
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
%
$$

**Solution function**

$$
 \boxed{y(x) = 2 + \frac{17}{3}x - 6x^{2} + \frac{4}{3} x^{3}}
$$

**Solution curve and data**

[image: cubic]

As Marty noted, the solution is exact.

Comment: Here is what I want : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsyOB.jpg. I dont want $f(2,5)$ to be negative. Thank you.