# Can I foresee the graph of an expression only looking at the formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

If I look at the ellipse's expression $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ it will look very similar to the circle's expression $x^2 +y^2 = 1$. The  only change I notice is that $a$ and $b$ are different, and if I have a bigger value of $a$ the ellipse will be flat on the x axis, different to the circle in which it has the same x, and y size on the axis!

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. You just described that you can see the graph of that equation only by looking at the formula, but I doubt you'd be able to see it for more complicated equations as easily. I don't really understand the point of this question, perhaps you should clarify

Comment: Could you help us understand what context you're looking at these from? Do you know any calculus?

Comment: Well... yes? If you have enough mathematics knowledge you could look at any expression and know what the graph is out of experience.

Comment: I found a subject in Multivariable Calculus(Level Curves and Graph Sketching) that answer my question, but thanks for the effort guys!

Answer (score 3):

Ellipse is a particular case of a *conic section*.
Here is the general equation of conic sections:
$$
Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0. \tag{1}
$$

Here is how we can distinguish the curve types by looking at the formula $(1)$:

(A) If $B^2-4AC<0$, then the curve is an ellipse or a circle or a point.

(B) If $B^2-4AC=0$, then the curve is a parabola or non-intersecting lines or one line.

(C) If $B^2-4AC>0$, then the curve is a hyperbola or two intersecting lines.

Comment: A lot more details can be found in [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Conic_parameters)

Comment: It's not exactally what I want, I mean, these formulas have aready been studied... I want to look at a expressions and give guesses about it's shape, do you understand?

Comment: Have you already mastered [graphs of rational functions](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/rational-expressions-equations-and-functions#graphs-of-rational-functions), [trigonometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions), polynomials, exponential functions? Once you know all of these, as well as conic sections, you will indeed be in many cases able to look at a function and predict the shape of its graph.

Comment: I aready master it, you're not getting mt point

Comment: We also need to keep in mind that very different expressions may in some cases produce similar-shaped graphs. For example, [look at this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2265908/equation-of-a-curve/). In the answers, very different formulas all produce graphs that look somewhat alike. On the other hand, the same general formula for conic sections describes ellipses as well as hyperbolas, and an ellipse does not resemble a hyperbola at all.

Comment: For example: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(pi%2Fx) {it doesn't have to be a conic section) I want to deduce how the function looks in the graph without taking a point in x and relating to y!

Comment: For simple enough expressions, it's possible to deduce the shape of the graph; to do so we need to study *coordinate transformations* and *types of expressions* (polynomial, rational, trigonometric, etc.) However, for very complex expressions the task is next to impossible.